# undetermined coefficient of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What would the undetermined coefficient, or 'guess' be for:

y''+4y = 16t+sin2t

I thought it would be (at+b)(sin2t+cos2t)
but it did not work.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is clearly about maths, not programming.

Comment: Use superposition - so have two guesses (separate, not multiplied like you have) that you will sum later. For the linear part, the guess should be `a*t` and for the periodic part `a*sin(2t) + b*cos(2t)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first guess should be `At + B + C*sin2t + D*cos2t`, but since there is no `y'` term, you can safely ignore the `B`. The other thing is that sin2t and cos2t are already homogeneous solutions, so you need to multiply that portion of the proposed solution by t. Again, since there is no `y'` term, you can ignore the sin2t part. So your guess should be

```
At + Bt*cos2t
```

And in fact the particular solution is `4t - t/4*cos2t`. [Wolphram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2b4y%20=%2016t%2bsin2t)